# Take data from a list of JSON, given by Mongo, faster

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-3.x

I need to retrieve info from mongo but using a for loop takes too much time to do that. I don't need the whole string that mongo gives, only some keys and insert one key. This is what I'm doing:

```
info = []
ids = []
for data in collection.find({'read':True}):
    ids.append(data['_id'])
    try:
        entity = data['results']['entities']
    except:
        continue
    entity.append({'read':False})
    info.append(entity)
```

Is there a way to get the value of the entities from data into the info list faster?

Comment: Why can't you make Mongo only return the entities?

Comment: In other words, Python can't improve your database performance, and you need a loop to get all the results

Comment: I just edited my code to a more realistic approach to what I'm doing

Comment: Okay, still. You're required to read the entire collection. You can't improve that process unless you can start a query from a specific offset, and split that offset value across multiple threads

Comment: how can I do that? I've been trying this: ´ ids = collection.find({'read':True},{'_ids':1}) ´ also for 'result.entities' but I get a pymongo.cursor.Cursor object
How can I access this data??

Comment: You need to iterate a Cursor object using a for loop like you've already done. Try `for id in ids`?